# FB.ui response callback not working on mobile device

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a function that triggers a Facebook share dialogue. When the user has successfully shared a site, the callback function calls a AJAX post that updates a counter in my database (rails). This works fine on desktop but when I test this on a mobile device (Safari), the callback function is not triggered at all:

```
function shareOnFacebook(){
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxx',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });
      FB.ui({
          method: 'share',
          name: 'foo',
          picture: 'http://mypic.com',
          href: 'http://mypage.com',
          description: 'descr'
      }, function(response) {
          if(response){
            $.ajax({
              url: "/my-app/post-url",
              type: 'POST',
              data: {
                some_id: 123
              }
            });
          }
          else{}
      });
    }
```

I digged through the docu but could not find any response on what I am doing wrong. Maybe you guys have a hint. Appreciated.

Comment: you do know that you will also get a response if the user hits "cancel"? or did you authorize the user with publish_actions?

Comment: that's not the point here - its about that callback not working at all. yes I know there is a response on cancel as well.

Comment: you should file a bug then: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/